# Как изменить цвет рамок таблицы в IE?

Tags: html, css, кроссбраузерность

Как изменить цвет рамок таблицы в IE? В Хроме, Мозиле и т.д. рамки указанного цвета, но в IE цвет рамок - черный.

```html
<table width="100%" bordercolor="#E7E7E7" border="2" align="center">
  <tr class="first-row">
    <td class="table-first" align="center"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td class="table-cenetr" align="center"><span class="table-captions">Варианты</span></td>
    <td class="table-end" align="center"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
td {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" align="center">
  <tr class="first-row">
    <td class="table-first" align="center"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td class="table-cenetr" align="center"><span class="table-captions">Варианты</span></td>
    <td class="table-end" align="center"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```